# I'm trying to match all characters before the 5th comma using regex

Tags: c#, regex

For example, I would need the output for this: 123, 456, 987, 321, 654, 741, 654,

to be this: 123, 456, 987, 321, 654

So far I have tried: ^(.+?),
This gives just the characters before the first comma: 123

The language is C#

Comment: You haven't specified a language that the regex will be used in and you haven't shown [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), which is why you're being downvoted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I hadn't provided enough information.
This is what I've tried so far: ^(.+?),
Which outputs just the characters before the first comma: 123
The language is C#

Comment: Some people, when presented with a problem, say "I know, I'll use a regex"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to extract first 5 numbers from your input:

```
^\d+(?:,\s*\d+){4}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA9dB8/1)

Comment: Thank you!! This worked. I have one more question: How would I select all characters between the 5th comma and the 10th?

Comment: For that you can use: [`^(?:\d+,\s*){5}((?:\d+,\s*){5})`](https://regex101.com/r/hA9dB8/2) and use captured group #1

Comment: I really appreciate the help a ton! I've never used regex or done anything in C# so this is super helpful. The last question I have is: how would I select all characters from the 5th comma to the last comma (without including the very last comma)?

Comment: Use [`^(?:\d+,\s*){5}((?:\d+,?\s*)*)\s*,\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/hA9dB8/3) and again use captured group #1

Comment: anubhava,
I just realized that I need these to be for any character, not just for numbers. So my string could be 1s2df1, 654dfgdf, 8s7f5s4, 321sd,
etc. I tried changiing the \d to . but that didn't solve it... Any ideas?

Comment: Try: `^\w+(?:,\s*\w+){4}`

Comment: Oh sorry about that! I gave the acceptance mark back. How would I alter the above code if the string contains dashes. So it might be: 
g123132-02, g123132-02, g123132-02, g123132-02, g123132-02, g123132-02,

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much.